# SuiteCRM 8.1 Problems Installing Can't Access the Folder 'Public" in Localhost XAMPP Windows

Tags: xampp, suitecrm, htdocs

Trying to install SuiteCRM 8.1 with XAMPP in Windows. I have downloaded and unzipped suitecrm 8.1 into the 'htdocs' folder. When I the load 'localhost/suitecrm/' I can see the folders within my crm folder. However when I click the 'public' folder to then install suitecrm I get, "This site can't be reached" and don't progress.

I have checked the httpd.conf file and have confirmed the "#" is not in front of the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so line. I thought this would fix the issue but it hasn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try downloading xampp with php version 7.4.29